# Trigger an event when CSS class is added: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm using ng2-modal for showing Bootstrap modals in my Angular 4 application. So, whenever the modal shows up a CSS class 'modal-open' is added to the body tag of the application (no matter on which page the modal is fired, the class is always added to the body):

[image]

I am trying to fire an event whenever this class is applied to body, that is whenever the modal shows up, so how can 'subscribe' (not sure if subscribe is the right word because it's usually used with RxJS lib) to that CSS class?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm using TinyMCE for a text editor and I want to execute the init method of that editor after the modal is shown (because TinyMCE has issues with Bootstrap modals, so they suggest initializing it after the modal has appeared).
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/bootstrap/

Comment: So you don't actually want to do something anytime the class is added to the body. Not even when any modal is being opened. But only when a specific modal is being opened. Why then don't you do what you need to do in the ngAfterViewInit (or ngAfterContentInit, to be tested) of the component displayed in that specific modal?

Comment: @JBNizet, the modal I'm using is not a component where I can define ngAfterViewInit, it's an NPM library 'ng2-modal' that lives in node_modules

Comment: can you use (onOpen)?

Comment: @Eliseo, the onOpen event is not correctly written in that library. Its fired even before the modal shows up, so not useful at all.